# мой пример сеттера (инкапсуляция)

Tags: java, setter

```
public class Human {

    private String name;
    private int age;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        if (age >=0){
            this.age = age;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Ошибка! Возраст не может быть отрицательным числом!");
        }
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}


public class Qwerty {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Human h1 = new Human();
        h1.setAge(-2);

        System.out.println(h1.getAge());
    }
}
```

Не пойму почему выводит:

```
0 После Ошибка! Возраст не может быть отрицательным числом!
```

Comment: И не забудьте принять ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что делаете, то и получаете.

Вы пытаетесь возраст задать в виде отрицательного числа

```
h1.setAge(-2);
          ^^
```

Поэтому метод

```
public void setAge(int age) {
    if (age >=0){
        this.age = age;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Ошибка! Возраст не может быть отрицательным числом!");
    }
}
```

выводит соответствующее сообщение на консоль.

После чего вы выводите текущее значение возраста

```
System.out.println(h1.getAge());
```

которое по умолчанию при создании объекта класса было инициализировано 0.

Обратите внимание, что вы забыли объявить поле `weight` в определении класса.

Comment: А ноль почему выводит?

Comment: @MikeMclaren Смотрите мой дополненный ответ.

Comment: @MikeMclaren из за проверки внутри сеттреа

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался